# Association Type mismatch

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to add User details into 2 tables The table Associations are

```
Distributor Table:

     class Distributor < ApplicationRecord

          has_one :authentication, dependent: :destroy
     end

Authentication Table

     class Authentication < ApplicationRecord

        belongs_to :distributor
        belongs_to :user

        validates :email,presence: true



        before_save :create_remember_token

        private
        def create_remember_token
           self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
        end

      end

Authentication table details


  Authentication(id: integer, email: string, password: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, admin: boolean, remember_token: string, user_id: integer, mail_confirmation: boolean, distributor: boolean, distributor_id: integer)
```

**Controller for create**

```
 def create
      @distributor = Distributor.new(distributor_params)
      if @distributor.save
         params[:distributor][:distributor_id] = @distributor.id
         params[:distributor][:password] = "Default"
         params[:distributor][:distributor] = "true"
         @authe_distributor = Authentication.new(authen_distributor_params)
         if @authe_distributor.save
              redirect_to @distributor
         else
              render 'new'
         end
       else
         render 'new'
       end

    end
```

whenever i am trying to add the details i getting this error.. anyone tell me what i am doing wrong..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Authentication` model has both a column and an association with the same name: distributor. This is problematic because all though you are trying to set the column named distributor to the `"true"` rails ends up trying to set the association to that value which is what causes the exception.

Rename either the column or the association so that you no longer have this clash and the problem should go away.